# Travelling from JFK to Jersey City

Tags: usa, public-transport, airport-transfer, jfk, new-jersey

How do I get from JFK to Jersey City NJ 07305 USA , What are the fastest options using Public Transportation ?

Comment: On the off-chance you're not aware of it, the "Public Transit" option in Google Maps can help you plan trips in major cities in the US.

Answer (score 7):

First, no options are particularly fast, but...

A) Take the AirTrain to Jamaica Station.

B) Take the E Train to World Trade Center

-or-

A) Take the AirTrain to Howard Beach

B) Take the A Train to Chambers Street

-then-

C) Exit at Vesey Street and walk one block West to World Trade Center PATH station.  Shortest.
-or- Follow the tunnels to Fulton Center and cross to the World Trade Center PATH station.  Underground.  I think there's still construction going on.

D) Take PATH to Exchange Place

E) Take the Hudson-Bergen Light Rail south.

Comment: One can now connect from the A train to the PATH without going outside, from either the Chambers St. station or the Fulton Street station.

Comment: @phoog That's great...about time!  Seems MTA hasn't updated the maps yet to reflect or even indicate this.

Comment: How would they indicate this on the map?  It's also possible to connect to Penn Station and Grand Central Station without going outside, as it has been for decades, but that's not shown on the map, either.

Comment: @phoog But Penn Station and Grand Central Station (4,5,6) are on opposite sides of town?

Comment: Yes.  These are separate connections.  Penn has connections to two MTA stations, one for the 8th Avenue line (A/C/E) and one for the 7th Avenue line (1/2/3).  Grand Central has a connection to one MTA station serving two lines, the 4/5/6 on the Lexington line and the 7 on the Flushing line.

Comment: @phoog Right, but neither have a connection to PATH.  That's at Herald Square.

Comment: Right, but PATH isn't part of the NYC subway system, and neither are the train services, so the ability to connect without going above ground should be represented similarly on the map.  If you want to limit it to the PATH system, though, there are MTA stations on 6th avenue that afford underground-only connections to PATH, and these are also not indicated on the map.

Comment: Note that AirTrain charges a ["sneaky" $5 exit fee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/getting-from-new-york-jfk-airport-to-manhattan-without-the-sneaky-airtrain-exit).  Of course, most of the other stuff you mention also costs money, but AirTrain is probably the least obvious one.

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

1. AirTrain to Jamaica Station
2. Long Island Rail Road to Penn Station
3. Walk one block to 33rd St PATH
4. Take PATH to Hoboken
5. Connect to Hudson-Bergen light rail

This would be a bit more expensive than Johns-305's answer, but could be a little faster since LIRR is generally quicker than subway.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a taxi from JFK to a PATH station in Manhattan but you might as well just take the JFK AirTrain to Jamaica and get the Long Island Rail Road into Penn Station as it is the fastest and most economical way to get into NYC. You'd then be one block from the 33rd Street PATH station.

Comment: Hello and welcome to travel.stackexchange! Hope you like it here. How is this answer any different than Nate Eldredge's answer above?